# Como realocar a caixa de paleta de cor do input(color)?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

O html, tem um tipo de input que ao click abre uma paleta de cor para o usuário escolher uma cor:

```html
<input type='color'>
```

[image: Ilustração do input]

Eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de editar essa caixa que aparece, estou interessado principalmente em como reposicionar ela. Pode ser por meio do css ou javascript (se for possível).

Comment: Essa caixa não é do HTML, é seu navegador que mostra assim. Em outros navegadores já muda tudo. Se quer uma caixa personalizada, não use esse input, faça uma própria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inicialmente, creio que não.

Como visto na [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color), que traduzi (elementarmente) abaixo, a informação é de que o componente é estilizado e exibido pelo navegador, e não conseguimos alterá-los. Não obstante, cada navegador exibe conforme seus próprios padrões de interface.

> A apresentação do elemento pode variar substancialmente de um navegador e/ou plataforma para outra — Este pode ser um simples
> 'input' textual que automaticamente valida a informação de cor para
> garantir que está em formato adequado, ou um seletor de cor no padrão
> da plataforma, ou algum tipo de janela de seletor de cor.

Caso sua situação exija que o seletor seja personalizado recomendo que use algo já pronto, como por exemplo: [Spectrum](https://seballot.github.io/spectrum/), [Pick-a-color](https://laurensperber.com/pick-a-color/),[Tiny Colorpicker](https://baijs.com/tinycolorpicker/)